# PHP revision control / edit history implementation

Tags: php, version-control, wiki

I'm trying to let users to edit certain text on some pages of my website. And, I want to maintain an Edit History of them so changes can easily be reverted back. So basically, I'm just trying to implement/integrate a super light-weight wiki into my existing website. All I need for it is a revision control and possibly a markdown support.

So, I'm wondering if any existing library or code exist for this kind of thing. If not, would it be advisable to implement the revision control using diff from scratch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should give [DokuWiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki) a quick look. I believe the main advantage is how easy it is to get running. It seems to do everything you are after, plus more:

> DokuWiki is wiki software aimed at small companies’ documentation needs. DokuWiki is licensed under GPL 2 and written in the programming language PHP. It works on plain text files and thus needs no database. Its syntax is similar to the one used by MediaWiki and makes sure the data files remain readable outside the wiki.
>
> #### Main features:
>
> - Revision control
> - Access control
> - Plugins
> - Templates
> - Internationalization and localization
> - Caching
> - Full text search